# Stop moving camera(LIBGDX)

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

hi everybody i've been trying to sto moving my camera at the end of my map, but it continue moving this is my code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {       
    //moving tiled map
    camera.position.x=camera.position.x+Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*200;

    camera.update();
    //...........................................

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    // renderer camera and map
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
    //...................................................

}

@Override
public void show() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();


    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map1.tmx");

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
}

@Override
public void hide() {


}

@Override
public void create() {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.position.set(width/2f, height/3f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
    camera.update();


}

@Override
public void render() {



}

@Override
public void pause() {


}

@Override
public void resume() {


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();

}
```

}

this is the code that move the camera on the map, but the camera dosen't stop moving at the end of the map, please help me guys how can i make the camera stop moving when it reach the end of the map??????

Comment: Get position where your map is rendered. If camere is out of the range, position of the map +- size of the map. Simply stop moving camera in that direction.

Comment: please veljiKo can u give me the code to stop moving the camera? :D

Comment: Your problem is detection of it i guess. Stop moving means you dont habe to update camera position. Can you provide code that renders your map. Im not sure what confuses you.

Comment: whith that code up there i can move my map with the camera but it dosen't stop at the end of the map it continue moving, do u know the code to stop moving the map?

Comment: Stop incrementing camera x position. I dont get it. Explain your problem nicely and give some more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth / 2 >= Float
            .parseFloat(currentMap.getProperties().get("width").toString())
            * TILE_SIZE) {
            camera.position.x = Float.parseFloat(currentMap.getProperties()
            .get("width").toString())
                    * TILE_SIZE - camera.viewportWidth / 2;
        }
```

Hope you understand the above mess!